# strange basic_string constructor c++17

Tags: c++, string, c++17

According [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) basic_string have 11 constructors.

11-th constructor seems very strange, because it take template unknown T type.

```
template < class T >
basic_string( const T& t, size_type pos, size_type n,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

As I know, it uses when construct string from string_view  from pos , and count characters.

*11) Implicitly converts t to a string view sv as if by `std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> sv = t;`, then initializes the string with the subrange [pos, pos + n) of sv as if by `basic_string(sv.substr(pos, n), a)`. This overload only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>>` is true.*

**Q: Why there DON'T added exactly**  `basic_string(basic_string_view, size_t pos, size_t count, Alloc  )`  **constructor?**

**Upd:  Q2: Where is useful this 11-th constructor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the note of this constructor:

> This overload only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>>` is `true`

**Q: Why there DON'T added exactly `basic_string(basic_string_view, size_t pos, size_t count, Alloc  )` constructor?**
**Ans:** As mentioned in above extract, the type `T` need not be of type `basic_string_view` but should be convertible in type `basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>` (May be via some `operator-overloading` or something).

**Where is useful this 11-th constructor?**
**Ans:** When `T` is not of type `basic_string_view`(i.e. `T` is not derived fom `basic_string_view`, directly or indirectly). But it is providing *some means(via `operator-overloading` or `friend-function` or something else) to convert `T` to `basic_string_view`*.

Comment: Thnx, Now I understand. However, this constructor may replace 3-separated constructors, (1) take const Char_T*, (2) std::basic_string, (3) std::basic_string_view  instead of T parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> Why didn't they just add a `basic_string_view` constructor?

They tried. It blew up `std::string s("ABCDE", 0, 1);` because `"ABCDE"` converts equally well to `basic_string` and `basic_string_view`, resulting in an ambiguity.

What you are seeing is basically a way to prefer the conversion to `basic_string_view`. It isn't pretty (such is the cost of retrofitting new overloads to an existing highly overloaded interface), but it works.